# wsgi error: Address already in use - socketio/django/apache2

Tags: python, django, socket.io, apache2, eventlet

My project is created with React (create-react-app), React router (no webpack), -- Django (rest) and Socketio with eventlet on the backend.
I have 3 problems with deployment with apache2 - **Everything worked perfectly on development**:

Created 2 conf files, one for the frontend port 80 and one for the backend port 8000 - separetely they work fine relatively.

The problem I have with deployment:

- Socket.io
  gives

```
[wsgi:error] 
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(("", 8000)), application, log_output=False)
sock.bind(addr)
Address already in use
```

- checked what uses the port --> only apache2 and it gives the same result with any other port
- tried to create a separate conf file for socket with port 5000 (changing the port in wsgi eventlet line), same result
  *the socketFile.conf:*

```
Listen 5000
<VirtualHost *:5000>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /home/path/to/main/folder>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess exampleSocket python-home=/home/path/to/venv python-path=/home/path/to/main/folder
WSGIProcessGroup exampleSocket
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

- the next line is done by default with eventlet (reuse_addr=True, reuse_port=None)
  `sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`

---

socketio_app/views.py

```
async_mode = None

import os
import socketio

basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sio = socketio.Server(
    async_mode=async_mode, 
    logger=False, 
    cors_allowed_origins='http://localhost:3000'
)
thread = None
...
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from socketio_app.views import sio
import socketio
import eventlet
import eventlet.wsgi

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "server.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()

application = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, application)

eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(("", 8000)), application, log_output=False)
```

Comment: i am also getting the same issue instead in using gunicorn with wsgi server

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental mistake is that you try to bind two processes on one tcp port on the same ip-address, that's impossible. 'Address already in use' is the error message that you'll get when you start another program that intends to use a socket that is already listening.

Use this command to find out if port 5000 is already in use:

ss -tln|grep 5000

I'd expect that Apache listens on port 80 (http) and the REST API on port 5000.